# Finding moment estimator and its asymptotic distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, poisson-distribution, moment-problem

I got a question:
We let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables with $X$ Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda$ and $Y$ exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda>0$ and we let $(X_1,Y_1),\ldots,(X_n,Y_n)$ be a sample from this distribution.

1. I have to find the moment estimator $\hat{\lambda}$ based on the statistic $t(x,y)=x-y$ and the sample $(X_1,Y_1),\ldots,(X_n,Y_n)$ and find the moment estimator's asymptotic distribution. Can anyone help me?

My thoughts so far is that: To find the asymtotic distribution I think I can use that $V(t(x,y))/m'(\lambda)^2$, but how do I find $m(\lambda)$? And can I then find moment estimator by solving $\lambda$ in $m(\lambda)$?

Comment: This same question, verbatim, was posted by another user: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4120156/moment-estimator-and-its-asymptotic-distribution-for-exponential-distribution

Comment: Is there something wrong with my question or is it not allowed to ask a question like this only added some ideas? Can see there are many viewers but do nobody have an idea to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the mean of $X_1-Y_1$ is $\lambda-\lambda^{-1}$. Thus, the [MM estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics)) of $\lambda$ is
$$
\hat{\lambda}_n=\frac{1}{2}\left(m_n+\sqrt{m_n^2+4}\right),
$$
where $m_n:=n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-Y_i)$. For the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{\lambda}_n$, note that
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(m_n-(\lambda-\lambda^{-1})\right)\xrightarrow{d}N\!\left(0,\lambda+\lambda^{-2}\right).
$$
Thus, using [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) with $g(x)=(x+\sqrt{x^2+4})/2$,
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\lambda}_n-\lambda\right)\xrightarrow{d}N\!\left(0,(\lambda+\lambda^{-2})[g'(\lambda-\lambda^{-1})]^2\right).
$$

Comment: But $\operatorname E(Y) = 1/\lambda\ne\lambda,$ since $\lambda$ is reported to be the _rate_. $\qquad$

Comment: $\text{“}$Exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda\text{”}$ means the distribution is $e^{-\lambda y} (\lambda\,dy)$ for $y>0.$ Thus the expected value is $$ \operatorname E(Y) = \int_0^\infty y \cdot e^{-\lambda y} (\lambda\,dy) = \frac 1 \lambda. $$

Comment: @d.k.o. The first and second moment of $X_1-Y_1$ are $\lambda - \frac{1}{\lambda}$ and $\lambda^2+\lambda +\frac{2}{\lambda^2}-2$, respectively

Comment: You're right. I misread the question and assumed that both $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are exponential r.v.s.

Comment: I think it makes sense now but should we not write  $\lambda- \frac{1}{\lambda}$ in stead of 0 now?

Comment: @Lifeni Instead of $0$? In which expression?

Comment: When we are finding the asymptotic distribution isn't the mean value we use there?

Comment: @Lifeni We use it on the LHS.

Comment: Thank you :-)!!