# Asymptotic distribution of maximum likelihood

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, poisson-distribution, moment-problem

I got a question:
We let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables with $X$ Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda$ and $Y$ exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda>0$ and we let $(X_1,Y_1),\ldots,(X_n,Y_n)$ be a sample from this distribution.

2. I have to find the asymptotic distribution for the maximum likelihood estimator.

I think we can use that $\tilde{\lambda} \sim(\lambda, ni(\lambda)^{-1} )$. But how can I find the Fisher Information $I(\lambda)$? Can anyone help me. Maybe this can help:
[Finding moment estimator and its asymptotic distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4120096/finding-moment-estimator-and-its-asymptotic-distribution)

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing it directly. Let $f(\lambda)$ be the log-likelihood after ignoring the additive terms that do not involve $\lambda$, then (please check my calculation)

$$
f(\lambda) = -n\lambda+\ln{\lambda}\sum {x_i} +n\ln{\lambda} -\lambda\sum{y_i}.
$$
Then differentiating with respect to $\lambda$ and equating it to zero get

$$
\hat{\lambda}= \frac{1+\bar{X}}{1+\bar{Y}}.
$$
By taking a second derivative you can see that it is indeed the maximum.
Then you can obtain the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{\lambda}$ in two steps

1. Use the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) to get the joint asymptotic distribution of
   $$
   \sqrt{n}\left((\bar{X},\bar{Y})^{\top}-\left(\lambda,\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)^{\top}\right)
   $$
2. Use [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) to get the asymptotic distribution of

$$
\sqrt{n}\left(g(\bar{X},\bar{Y})^{\top}-g\left(\lambda,\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)^{\top}\right),
$$

where $g(a,b):= \frac{1+a}{1+b}$.